# SQL update statement inserting PeopleID into child tables to link data

Tags: sql

I need to place the PeopleID in several tables for my new database to link all of the peole information.   I have tried several times to write a simple update statement please help.  Every time I get close I get AMBIGUOUS COLUMN ERROR   I don't know what else to do.

Update CONTRACT
    Set PeopleID = B.PeopleID
from People A
    Inner join
    (
        Select PeopleId, F.ContractID
        From People A
            Inner Join Person PRSN on PRSN.PersonID = A.PersonID
            Inner Join DARPA_IMPORT_REAL..persnl oldP on oldP.pl_pid = PRSN.PersonID
            Left outer join Contract F on F.ContractID = oldP.kn_254id
    ) B on A.PeopleID = B.PeopleID
Go

Comment: Share some more information, like your database structure, we don´t know what it looks like, so we can´t possible help you this way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Update CONTRACT Set CONTRACT.PeopleID = B.PeopleID 
        from People A 
            Inner join ( 
                        Select A.PeopleId, F.ContractID 
                            From People AA
                                Inner Join Person PRSN on PRSN.PersonID = AA.PersonID 
                                Inner Join DARPA_IMPORT_REAL..persnl oldP on oldP.pl_pid = PRSN.PersonID 
                                Left outer join Contract F on F.ContractID = oldP.kn_254id ) B 
                    on A.PeopleID = B.PeopleID
```

you were asigning the ´A´ alias twice so I recomend using different aliases always